# Project Management Software similar to Redmine or Trac

Tags: project-management, task-management

Is there any decent free project/task management software out there with tasks management? I am looking for something similar to Trac or Redmine, but I would also like subtasking my tasks as well. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Voted to move this to SuperUser, which it is better suited for

Comment: From the FAQ: "software tools commonly used by programmers". The pieces of software I listed here are used to manage development workflow, so while I can see it belonging on Superuser, I feel it also fits within the scope of this site as well.

Comment: Agreed - the faq could do with being updated now there are so many other Stack sites. Regardless, SuperUser is *more* suited to your question and you'll likely get a better selection of answers over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Project Kaizer](http://www.projectkaiser.com/). It supports unlimited subtasking and is free for up to 5 users.

Comment: Well the one answer was enough, we chose to use this one for the sake of it being able to handle subtasks

Comment: "Pefrect Project Management" and an utterly unmaintained blog really do instill confidence… but it it was a lot more active back in 2011, to be fair.